# Getting excel file from anywhere in computer with openpyxl/Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Im working on a project to automate some excel processes, but so far I have only found a way to select excel files if theyre in the same folder as the python file. how do i make it to where i can select the excel file without it being in the same folder as python? I know i can type the whole path, but i would like to only use the file name to select it("sample.xlsx")

Comment: Do you want it to search your entire disk drive for the file??  It's possible, but slow.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Thats fine, Im not really worried about the time/speed. As long as funtionality is good, it shouldnt be a proble,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python built-in tkinter filedialog.
A simple sample would be:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

path2urExcel = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select the desired excel sheet  ..")
```

Then proceed with your script.